# Expl3 loop with labels package

Tags: expl3

I've trying to use an `expl3` loop to output a page of labels with the `labels` package.

With the `labels` package, every label should be separated by a blank line.

I'm having trouble getting whatever I need for the blank line into my `expl3` loop.

In the MWE, the first page shows a page of labels created by inserting the label code 33 times. The second page shows how my loop code doesn't work :).

How can I do this?

```
% TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=11
\LeftPageMargin=6.5mm
\RightPageMargin=6.5mm
\TopPageMargin=14mm
\BottomPageMargin=14mm
\InterLabelColumn=2.5mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=2mm
\RightLabelBorder=2mm
\TopLabelBorder=2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=2mm

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \dcp_format_label:
  {
    \centering\large
    \emoji{glowing-star} ~ Well ~ Done ~ St ~ Paul ~ Stars! ~ \emoji{glowing-star}
  }
\cs_new:Nn \dcp_output_labels:n
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {#1}
    \begin{labels}
      \int_do_while:nn { \l_tmpa_int <= \l_tmpb_int }
        {
          \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
          \dcp_format_label:
          % somehow need whatever the label package sees as a blank line here (not \par)
        }
    \end{labels}
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \outputlabels \dcp_output_labels:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \formatlabel \dcp_format_label:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{labels}
\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\end{labels}

\clearpage

\outputlabels{33}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `labels` environment starts with:

```latex
\def\start@@label{%
 \begin{lrbox}{\this@label}%
  \begin{minipage}{\area@width}\raggedright%
  \catcode `\^^M =\active % <--- here
  \@gobblecr%
}
```

which means it expects the end line character to be catcode 13, so you have to do `` \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^^M } `` before defining the `\dcp_output_labels:n` command.

Additionally, the environment scans its body using a macro delimited by `^^M`<sub>13</sub>, so your `\int_do_while:nn` loop won't work, because it happens after the environment has already started: you need to put all the `^^M`<sub>13</sub> in place *before* the environment starts.  You can use:

```latex
          \prg_replicate:nn {#1}
            { \dcp_format_label: \exp_not:N ^^M \exp_not:N ^^M }
```

to make `#1` copies of `\dcp_format_label: ^^M ^^M` when used inside an `e`- or `x`-expansion.

Putting all that together gives two pages with:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

\LabelCols=3
\LabelRows=11
\LeftPageMargin=6.5mm
\RightPageMargin=6.5mm
\TopPageMargin=14mm
\BottomPageMargin=14mm
\InterLabelColumn=2.5mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\LeftLabelBorder=2mm
\RightLabelBorder=2mm
\TopLabelBorder=2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=2mm

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dcp_format_label:
  {
    \centering\large
    \emoji{glowing-star} ~ Well ~ Done ~ St ~ Paul ~ Stars! ~ \emoji{glowing-star}
  }
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { 13 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dcp_output_labels:n
  {
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:N \begin{labels}
          \prg_replicate:nn {#1}
            { \dcp_format_label: \exp_not:N ^^M \exp_not:N ^^M }
        \exp_not:N \end{labels}
      }
  }
\group_end:
\cs_new_eq:NN \outputlabels \dcp_output_labels:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \formatlabel \dcp_format_label:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{labels}
\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\formatlabel

\end{labels}

\clearpage

\outputlabels{33}
\end{document}
```